# KIbana isn’t showing newly created indicies

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I created 3 indicies on my elastisearch opened up kibana and all those showed up on it. After a few days I created 2 more indicies and opened up my kibana but I only see those 3 indicies I created for the first time and not the new ones.

I tried searching for those indicies in Discover but nothing shows up.

Everything is running locally on my laptop

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

In the Kibana Discover view, you don't see indexes, but **index patterns**, which are a way of grouping indexes together under a single logical name, similar to an [alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-add-alias.html).

For instance, if your index pattern is called `my-index-*` then you'll see all indexes called `my-index-1`, `my-index-2`, etc

If you create new indexes, the key is to use a name that will match the index pattern that you've created. If you create `my-index-999` then it will be visible in the Discover view immediately without further action. If you create an index called `another-index-1` then it will not be visible until you create an appropriate index pattern that matches this name.